# Node.js backend API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

So, im currently re-writing my api from the following:

```
function getAirplaneCompany(id) {
        return airPlaneCompany.findOne({_id: id}).then(function (firm) {
            return firm;
        });
    }
```

to this:

```
exports.getAirplaneCompany = function (req,res) {
    return airPlaneCompany.findOne({_id: id}).then(function (firm) {
        return res.json(firm);
    });
};
```

Could i call `getAirplaneCompany` function like i normally do within another controller?

for example:

```
exports.PlaneExpensesFromXToY = function (req,res) {
    return getAirplaneCompany(someID).then(function (response) {
        // do something with it here;
    });
};
```

also to get the id from `getAirplaneCompany`, is it right to do it as :

```
exports.getAirplaneCompany = function (req,res,id) {
    return airPlaneCompany.findOne({_id: id}).then(function (firm) {
        return res.json(firm);
    });
};
```

?

How would i then call it from `PlaneExpensesFromXToY` func?

edit:

planning on calling it like: `router.post('/ships/get',ships.getSpecificCompany());`

Edit two:

The reason im re-writing it and need to get req and res is because im looking for a way to emit socket.io events inside some of the functions.

As i have searched for almost a year, it seems like this is the approatch i need to have to accomplish to use socket.io within it.

As an addition, ive read about restful api`s and how they should look.
examples:

```
router.post('/gang/garage/withdraw',gangs_model.withdrawGangCar());
router.post('/gang/garage/donate',gangs_model.donateCarToGang());
```

update 3:
gangs_model and ships, are alike this:

```
var ships_model = require('./app/gamemodels/ship_model.js');
```

Comment: Okay, so you want `PlaneExpensesFromXToY` and `getAirplaneCompany` to be linked with routes and inside `PlaneExpensesFromXToY` you want to call `getAirplaneCompany`.?

Comment: @RaghavGarg yeah. But , main issue is socket.io, im doing all this just to use socket.io :P

Comment: Then you would have to make another function which would make actual db call of `findOne` and you will access this newly made function from both the routes to get a single truth.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the same function for a call from another controller AND for route request I would suggest something like:

```
function getSpecificCompany(id){
  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    airPlaneCompany.findOne({_id: id})
       .then(function (firm) {
           resolve(firm);
       })
       .catch(function(err){
          reject(err);
       });
  });
}
```

In routes you would do something like:

```
route.get('airplaneCompany/:id, getAirplaneCompany);
```

In route function you could do:

```
exports.getAirplaneCompany = function (req, res) {
    getSpecificCompany(req.params.id)
       .then(function(company){
            res.json(company);
       });
};
```

The same usage would apply from a different controller.

```
exports.PlaneExpensesFromXToY = function (req, res) {
    getSpecificCompany(someID).then(function (response) {
        // do something with it here;
    });
};
```

Comment: router.post('/ships/get',ships.getSpecificCompany());
how can i do the approatch here too?

Comment: cause, im planning to do this only to get socket.io within it.

Comment: Route '/ships/get/:id' would not call getSpecificCompany(), but its route "handler", e.g. route.post('/ships/get/:id, getShip). Note: not function call. Then in getShip you would call getSpecificCompany and pass req.body.params.id as a param for id you are searching by.